# Looking For Ways To Update Chromedriver Options

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application that tests various custom Chrome extensions with various sites. My current code looks like this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("extension1.zip"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://site1.com");
// Evaluate page
driver.quit();

options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("extension2.zip"));
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://site2.com");
// Evaluate page
driver.quit();
```

There is a lot of overhead associated with opening and closing the browser. Over time, the application gets slower and slower. I would like to be able to remove and add extensions without opening and closing the driver and the browser. Each site needs to be evaluated with only one of the extensions. Currently, I'm evaluating 8 sites and 8 extensions, but the number of sites and extensions will grow over time.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See if this will remove previously added extensions:

```
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
```

The entire code is

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

Comment: No, that doesn't remove the extensions. It would just disable them. Also, the requirement stated in the question was to avoid recreating a new WebDriver on each test.

Comment: Well, it it were removing previously extensions you could just remove the previous and add a new one each time using the same WebDriver. But if this does not work we have to look for another solution.